# Drupal 8 issue with caching render array

Tags: caching, drupal-8

I have a problem with drupal 8. I am trying to cache a render array this way :

```
$meetingsView = [
    '#theme' => 'meetings_view',
    '#meetings_view' => $meetings,
    '#months' => $this->monthsArray,
    '#sidebar' => [
    '#theme' => 'meetings_sidebar',
        '#search_meetings_form' => $searchMeetingsForm,
    ],
    '#language' => $language,
    '#children' => $meetingRows,
    '#attached' => [
        'library' => [
            'my_module/my_module',
        ],
        'drupalSettings' => [
            'siteUrl' => $base_url,
        ],
    ],
    '#cache' => [
        'keys' => ['meeting_views'],
        'context' => [],
        'tags' => ['http_response'],
        'max-age' => 60,
    ],
];
```

I return it at the end of a controller method bound to a route to see a list of meetings.

Sadly the page never use my max-age (60 seconds).

When I use

```
$cacheMetadata = new CacheableMetadata();
$cacheMetadata->setCacheContexts([]);
$cacheMetadata->setCacheMaxAge(60);
$cacheMetadata->setCacheTags([]);

$markup = $renderer->renderRoot($meetingsView);

$response = new HtmlResponse($markup, Response::HTTP_OK);
$response->addCacheableDependency($cacheMetadata);
```

and return the response, the page is successfully cached with the good max-age but do not use the theme template, and therefore appear without style and page markup.

Could you please help me to find a solution: either succeed to cache the render array or succeed to render the response within my theme.

Best,

PF

Comment: I think I might have found the solution. Within a render array you must cache every child (#children), it means create a cache array in the render array for every level of your render array. Therefore I created a cacheID based on query parameters and level (within the loop) and used this cid as cache keys. `$cid = 'api:' . \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId() . ':meetings:' . http_build_query($parameters, '', ':');` for the parent array, by example. I'll keep the thread updated while I make more tests.

Comment: Everything seems OK. My last issue is that the same page but called from a form submit does not cache. I will investigate.

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have found the solution. Within a render array you must cache every child (#children), it means create a cache array in the render array for every level of your render array. Therefore I created a cacheID based on query parameters and level (within the loop) and used this cid as cache keys.

```
$cid = 'api:' . \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId() . ':meetings:' . http_build_query($parameters, '', ':');
```

for the parent array, by example.

```
'#cache' => [
  'keys' => [$cid],
  'context' => [],
  'tags' => ['http_response'],
  'max-age' => $cache_expire,
],
```

and in the children

```
'#cache' => [
  'keys' => [
    $cid,
    'meeting_rows:' . $i,
  ],
  'context' => [],
  'tags' => ['http_response'],
  'max-age' => $cache_expire,
],
```